# Django Rest Framework Can OrderingFilter use the name define in serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying django rest framework `OrderingFilter`

The function works well, the only question is the field name is depend on  models
But the front-end engineer don't need to know the backend model table schema.

When they call api they will get the data format :

```
   {
        "order_id": 3,
        "name": "test",
        "app_id": 2,
        "nearly_app": "app1"
    },
```

But the `order_id` actually is `id` in the model
 `app_id` actually is `app` in the model
 `nearly_app` actually is `app.app_name` in the model

I mean I can search `/api/?ordering=id`,`/api/?ordering=-app`
Can I edit to  `/api/?ordering=order_id`,`/api/?ordering=-app_id`  to let the front-end use it ?

**views.py**

```
class DataList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Serializer
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='id')
    app_id = serializers.CharField(source='app.id')
    nearly_app = serializers.CharField(source='app.app_name')

    class Meta:
    model = Data
    fields = ('order_id','name','app_id','nearly_app')
```

**models.py**

```
class App(models.Model):
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    app_desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Data(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(App,null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'app')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend default [OrderingFilter](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/filters.py#L195) and do your param mapping inside `def get_ordering()` then use this custom ordering class under `filtering_backends` in your views.